# Keep highscore through app updates with swift

Tags: ios, swift

If I use `NSUserDefaults` to save the highscore, the highscore will stay if I upgrade the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `NSUserDefaults` will stay during App updates.

However, best practice is to save the score via Game Center, iCloud, or any other online storage to avoid lose of data. Facebook is a good choice too.